# NullPointerException while setting adapter to the gridView in onPostExecute()

Tags: android

I have Activity with fragment where I want to display images in GridView. NullPointerException appears while assigning adapter to the gridview in onPostExecute method.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

**MainActivityFragment.java**

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

private final String API_KEY = BuildConfig.MOVIE_DB_API_KEY;
private final String  POSTER_BASE_PATH ="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/";
// posible poster sizes "w92", "w154", "w185", "w342", "w500", "w780", or "original"
private final String POSTER_SIZE = "w185";
private MoviesAdapter moviesAdapter;

public MainActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    return rootView;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_download){
        DownloadMovies downloadTask = new DownloadMovies();
        downloadTask.execute();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class DownloadMovies extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Movie[]>{
    private String LOG_TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();


    private Movie[] getMoviesFromJson(String json) throws JSONException{

        final String MOVIE_POSTER_PATH = "poster_path";
        final String MOVIE_IS_FOR_ADULTS = "adult";
        final String MOVIE_OVERVIEW = "overview";
        final String MOVIE_RELASE_DATE = "release_date";
        final String MOVIE_ID = "id";
        final String MOVIE_ORIGINAL_TITLE = "original_title";
        final String MOVIE_ORIGINAL_LANGUAGE = "original_language";
        final String MOVIE_TITLE = "title";
        final String MOVIE_BACKDROP_PATH = "backdrop_path";
        final String MOVIE_POPULARITY = "popularity";
        final String MOVIE_VOTE_COUNT = "vote_count";
        final String MOVE_VOTE_AVERAGE = "vote_average";


        JSONObject moviesJson = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray moviesArray = moviesJson.getJSONArray("results");
        Movie[] movies = new Movie[moviesArray.length()];

        for (int i=0; i<moviesArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject movieJsonObject = moviesArray.getJSONObject(i);

            movies[i] = new Movie(
                    POSTER_BASE_PATH + POSTER_SIZE + movieJsonObject.getString(MOVIE_POSTER_PATH),
                    movieJsonObject.getString(MOVIE_IS_FOR_ADULTS),
                    movieJsonObject.getString(MOVIE_OVERVIEW),
                    movieJsonObject.getString(MOVIE_RELASE_DATE),
                    movieJsonObject.getString(MOVIE_ID),
                    movieJsonObject.getString(MOVIE_ORIGINAL_TITLE),
                    movieJsonObject.getString(MOVIE_ORIGINAL_LANGUAGE),
                    movieJsonObject.getString(MOVIE_TITLE),
                    movieJsonObject.getString(MOVIE_BACKDROP_PATH),
                    movieJsonObject.getString(MOVIE_POPULARITY),
                    movieJsonObject.getString(MOVIE_VOTE_COUNT),
                    movieJsonObject.getString(MOVE_VOTE_AVERAGE)
            );
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, movies[i].toString());
        }
        return movies;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Movie[] doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        String movieJSONStr;

        //final String MOVIE_DB_BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?";
        final String MOVIE_DB_BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc";
        final String API_PARAM= "api_key";
        try{
            Uri buildUri = Uri.parse(MOVIE_DB_BASE_URL).buildUpon().
                    appendQueryParameter(API_PARAM,API_KEY).build();

            URL url = new URL(buildUri.toString());
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Url:  " + url);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) return null;

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }
            if (buffer.length() == 0) return null;

            movieJSONStr = buffer.toString();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Movies " + movieJSONStr);

        } catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error " ,e);
            return null;

        } finally {
            if (urlConnection !=null){
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null){
                try{
                    reader.close();
                } catch ( final IOException e){
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        try{
            return getMoviesFromJson(movieJSONStr);
        } catch (JSONException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Movie[] result) {
        if(result != null){
            //super.onPostExecute(result);
            GridView gridView = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.posters_grid);
            moviesAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(getActivity(), Arrays.asList(result));
            gridView.setAdapter(moviesAdapter);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**MoviesAdapter.java**

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {
private static final String LOG_TAG = MoviesAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

public MoviesAdapter(Activity context, List<Movie> moviesList){
    super(context, 0, moviesList);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    Movie movie = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.movie_item, parent, false);
    }

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.poster_imageview);
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(movie.getPosterPath()).into(imageView);

    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movie_title_textview);
    textView.setText(movie.getTitle());

    return convertView;
  }
}
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnWidth="150dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
tools:context=".MainActivityFragment"
android:id="@+id/posters_grid">
</GridView>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment"
android:name="pl.example.movies.MainActivityFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

**StackTrace**

```
03-03 12:20:29.947  32590-32590/pl.example.movies E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: pl.example.movies, PID: 32590
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at pl.example.movies.MainActivityFragment$DownloadMovies.onPostExecute(MainActivityFragment.java:189)
        at pl.example.movies.MainActivityFragment$DownloadMovies.onPostExecute(MainActivityFragment.java:72)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

Error occurs in this line(189):

```
gridView.setAdapter(moviesAdapter);
```

Right behind this line(187):

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.posters_grid);
```

So it's hard for me to understand what mistake I made here.

Comment: I don't see you have implemented GetCount method in your Adapter class. And also I feel `gridView` might be null in your case.

Comment: GridView is null. Do you know how can I fix this?

Comment: You are calling Async Task from your Menu Items. I feel those Menu Items are not inside your Fragment, right?

Comment: They are inside MainActivity. I tried to move onCreateOptionsMenu method to MainActivityFragment but I still got NullPointerException.

Comment: Can you please join this chat [room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105253/nullpointerexception-while-setting-adapter-to-the-gridview-in-onpostexecute)

Comment: I can't, I need 20 reputation points. But I fix this problem. I initialize gridView and adapter in onCreateView and then in onPostExecute just addAll values to movieAdapter. Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: Thats great! :) Thanks! Happy Coding :)